# RewriteBase - leads me to same directory?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-routing

I have built myself a small MVC with following htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?controller=$1 [QSA,L]
```

when I now click on a link `http://example.com/mycontroller/` I get to the controller `mycontroller`.. everything works fine here.

but inside `http://example.com/mycontroller/` I have further links i.e. `http://example.com/mycontroller/edit/1` which lead me to `http://example.com/mycontroller/mycontroller/edit/1` (?)

how can that be? how can I fix this?

Comment: Just because you are using human-readable URL does not make it MVC.

Comment: I think you are using codeigniter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do the links in your HTML look like?

`<a href="/mycontroller/edit/1" ...` or `<a href="mycontroller/edit/1" ...` ?

The latter is relative to the current path, and when you're already at `/mycontroller/`, it will expand to `/mycontroller/mycontroller/edit/1`

To solve this you need to make your links server-relative (i.e. begin with a `/`)